# In c# dot net how to get outlook meeting room capacity attribute?

Tags: c#-4.0, server, exchange-server

I am using c# and trying to read outlook meeting information using Microsoft Directory services.
[image]
I am success to read lots information using Directory services but I am not able to get meeting room capacity and not getting any proper help in google.

I am using Microsoft Exchange server 2010 and using dot net 2012.

Thanks,
Harish Rawat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resource capacity should be held in the msExchResourceCapacity property you should be able to see all the properties on an object if you just use ADSIedit to browse one of the Meeting Room's where that property has been configured.

Comment: I was checked with msExchResourceCapacity it returning nothing.